# Identical muliplicity for eigenvalues of Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Suppose $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$ is a bounded simply connected domain. Consider the Laplacian eigenvalue problem with Dirichlet boundary condition :

\begin{cases} 
      \hfill \Delta u=\lambda u  \hfill & \Omega \\
      \hfill u=0 & \partial\Omega. \\
  \end{cases}
$\textbf Q1:$ Is that the case that all eigenvalues are of the same multiplicity?(It seems very unlikely, but what are some examples?)

$\textbf Q2:$If the answer to the first question is negative, is there a characterization of domains that satisfy the property in $(\textbf Q1)$?

$\textbf {Edit 1:}$ This [link](http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1006595115793#page-1) sounds  interestinhg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a simple example where solutions are
$$
    \phi_{n,m}(x,y)=\sin(n x)\sin(m y),\;\;\; \Omega = [0,\pi]\times[0,\pi].
$$
The associated eigenvalues are $-(n^{2}+m^{2})$. The base eigenvalue is $\lambda=-2$, and this eigenspace has multiplicity $1$. The next is $\lambda=-5$, which is of multiplicity $2$.

It's common to have multiplicity $1$ for the base eigenvalue because the base eigenfunction typically cannot vanish inside.

Based on the comments, it's worth adding:
$$
\begin{align}
      \mbox{Multiplicity 2 ($\lambda=-3$):}&\; 1^2+2^2 = 2^2+1^2 \\
      \mbox{Multiplicity 3 ($\lambda=-50$):}&\; 1^2+7^2 = 7^2+1^2 =5^2+5^2 \\
      \mbox{Multiplicity 4 ($\lambda=-65$):}&\; 1^2+8^2 = 8^2+1^2 = 4^2+7^2 = 7^2+4^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Aren't the rest, all of multiplicity 2?

Comment: The first is of mulpticity one, the second one of multiplicity two, so it is already a counterexample to your first claim @BigM

Comment: Agreed. Well first eigenvalue is always simple, the second apparently is at most of multiplicity three  https://eudml.org/doc/139642. I was hoping maybe for a big class of domains all the eigenvalues but a few have the same multiplicity.

Comment: @BigM I will guess that for Q1, it is generic that all eigenvalues are of multiplicity one, since somehow higher multplicities comes from some symmetry of $\Omega$. For example, if we consider $\Omega = [0,1] \times [0,r]$ for some $r\neq 1$, then all eigenvalues are simple.

Comment: @BigM : $1^{2}+7^{2}=7^{2}+1^{2}=5^{2}+5^{2}$. So in this problem we have multiplicity $1,2,3$. Are there others? Yes, $8^2+1^2 = 1^2+8^2=4^2+7^2=7^2+4^2$. So, multiplicity $1,2,3,4$.

Comment: @TrialAndError : Note that everything are off by a $\pi^2$ now.

Comment: @JohnMa : I put the $\pi$ into the domain instead now. That's easier to fix. :)

Comment: I did a little research in the literature and learnt that $m(\lambda_n)\leq2n-3$ for $n\geq3$. See [here](http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1006595115793#page-1)

Comment: @BigM : That's for a manifold without boundary and of genus 0, which is not what we have here. Very interesting reference.

Comment: @TrialAndError good point. totally neglected the fact that, the paper is on manifolds "without" boundary. Simply connectedness implies genus zero though.

Comment: @BigM : You could roll this up into torus with periodicity and apply if it weren't for that pesky genus. Fun problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generically all eigenvalues have the same multiplicity: One.

This is [a result of K. Uhlenbeck](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374041) in the context of Riemannian manifolds of dimension $> 1$. I don't know a reference off the top of my head for simply connected planar domains but it would be wildly surprising if the result were different.