# Subleading terms in Weyl's Law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, laplacian

The two term Weyl's Law states that
$$N(\lambda)\sim\frac{area(\Omega)}{4\pi}\lambda-\frac{perimeter(\partial\Omega)}{4\pi}\sqrt\lambda$$
where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $R^2$, and $N(\lambda)$ is the number of eigenvalues (with multiplicity) $\leq\lambda$ in the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem for the Laplacian.

I know we can get the leading term using min-max theorems. How would I go about finding the second term, at least for some easy domains like rectangles.

Comment: I found this [paper](http://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0206524) for domains in which separation of variable is applicable and similar papers on circle, elliptic and polygonal domains. But they are in Russian. Any way to get them in English?

Comment: I seem to recall Courant-Hilbert goes through this by approximating the boundary with triangles.

Comment: For a rectangle, the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are explicit. The eigenfunctions are products of cosines. From that, deriving Weyl's law should be  relatively straightforward.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1537640/8157) for an example of explicit eigenfuctions, as per my previous comment.

Comment: @Neal I don't think he works out the second term.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro for the rectangle this is equivalent to asymptotic error terms in counting the number of integral lattice points in an ellipse, which is not trivial

Comment: @antrep1234 Ok you have probably looked more recently than I have.. I will see if I can find a good reference.

Comment: @Neal: You are absolutely right. The problem is not trivial even for a square. My comment on the law being "straightforward" is wrong. Actually, this is very interesting, thanks a lot for your remark.